# Присвоить всем записям рандомный уникальный id

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с 50000 записями, хочу присвоить всем уникальный рандомный цифровой id, не по порядку. Пусть будет в диапазоне 10 000 000 - 99 999 999. Возможно ли составить такой запрос?

Comment: используйте метку времени (timestamp) - количество миллисекунд начиная с какого-то момента.

Comment: Можно написать функцию, которая будет генирировать число(id) в указаном диапазоне, проверять есть ли в базе запись с таким id, если нет, то обновлять у первой необновленной записи id, если есть, то запускать эту функцию заново

Comment: Михаил, хотелось совсем беспорядочный рандом. Максим, тоесть одним запросом никак? 50000 селектов и апдейтов делать придется?

Comment: 50000 селектов и апдейтов займут у вас ну пусть две минуты. Вы дольше вопрос этот писали.

Comment: Можно принять id 1й записи равной 10 000 000 и добавлять к каждому следующему id случайное значение в диапазоне от 1 до 1799 - получите возрастающую последовательность из уникальных чисел. 1799 = (99 999 999 - 10 000 000) / 50 000 - такое значение гарантирует, что максимальное значение id не привысит 99 999 999 (хотя это излишнее предостережение - rand(X) не вернет максимальное значение 50000 раз :-) подряд. На oracle это точно можно сделать 1 запросом. Как в mysql - не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update randTest K
  join (
        select A.id,B.RND
          from (
            select id, @m:=@m+1 M
              from (select @m:=0) N,
                   randTest
          ) A,
          (
           select RND,@n:=@n+1 N
             from (
               select distinct RND RND
                 from (
                   select 10000000+ceil(rand()*100000000)%90000000 RND
                     from randTest R,
                          (select 1 union all select 2) S
                 ) X
             ) Y, (select @n:=0) N
         ) B
       where B.N=A.M
  ) L on K.id=L.id
set id=L.RND
```

До начала update предполагается, что в поле ID уже есть некое уникальное значение, либо есть другое уникальное поле, на основании которого можно выполнить join L-K. Если начальные id строго с 1 подряд без разрывов, то подзапрос `A` можно убрать и использовать в качестве id `B.N`.

Общий алгоритм: Так как изначально случайные числа могут повторятся, то за счет склейки с `S` создаем в 2 раза больше случайных чисел, чем записей в таблице. Выбираем из них уникальные (`Y`). Нумеруем (`A`) и склеиваем с пронумерованными по порядку начальными ID (`B`). На выходе в `L` получаем список всех текущих ID с уникальным случайным значением для каждого из них. Остается подклеить эти значения по ID к изменяемой таблице.